# Finding mgf of a gamma random variable and finding $3rd$ moment

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions, gamma-distribution

> Give the mgf of a gamma random variable having mean $6$ and variance
>   $12$, and then use the mgf to obtain the $3rd$ moment of the random
>   variable.

I have that

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(X)&=\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2} \\
\operatorname{E}(X)&=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}
\end{align}

From the given mean and variance, I obtain $\alpha=3$, $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$.

The Wikipedia Page says that the mgf of a gamma distribution is

$$\left(1-\frac{t}{\beta}\right)^{-\alpha}$$

So I have that the mgf in my case is

$$\left(1-2t\right)^{-3} I_{(-\infty, \beta)}(t)$$

since the Wiki page says $t \lt \beta$.

I think to find the $3rd$ moment, I would take the third derivative of this and then plug in $t=0$.

$$\frac{d^3}{dt^3}\left(1-2t\right)^{-3}=\frac{480}{(1-2t)^6}=480$$

Are these correct?

Comment: This also isn't a question about statistics.  While you might use a gamma distribution in statistical inference or testing, this question isn't about any of those techniques, and is entirely about probability theory.

Comment: Assuming that $I_{(-\infty,\beta)}$ is the indicator function, your work looks correct to me---I don't see any obvious mistakes, and your assertion that the third moment is $M'''(0)$ is correct (where $M$ is the mgf).

Comment: Yeah I meant it as the indicator function. Thanks!